Kcross.inhom in R spatstat envelope not around theoretical distribution curve
I am trying to analyse how two point patterns are relates to each other spatially. More specifically, I have dataset A of settlements known from historical (written sources) and dataset B of known archaeological sites from the same area. I want to test how well B predicts the location of A, in other words if there is a point B, how likely is it that there is a point A nearby.
I got a hint I should use the K-cross test for that. When reading further, I got thr idea I should test for homogeinity. I used the quadrat test, it rejected the null hypothesis. I concluded I have to use the inhomogenous variant of kcross, the kcross.inhom.
Now, here's the problem. When I use the kcross.inhom in spatstat, something strange happens; the confidence envelope isn't plotted around the theoretical distribution curve, but completely separately. It shouldn't be like that, right? When I perform the usual kcross, it's okay, the result seems logical.
I have uploaded my data as well as my notebook with code and results here. Very much appreciate any advice:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1W8JpLYjX8S4vLh5MU16S1BQ8J--VXZ1M

This is a frequently asked question.
There are three main reasons:

The "inhomogeneous" functions like Kinhom, Kcross.inhom, Kdot.inhom expect an argument lambda, lambdaI or similar which is an estimate of the intensity function of the point process. Strictly speaking, the inhomogeneous K function estimate is only valid if the intensity function is given exactly. Errors in estimating the intensity can severely affect the validity of the inhomogeneous K function estimate. If the user does not supply the argument lambda or lambdaI etc, the default is to calculate an intensity estimate using kernel smoothing applied to the dataset. This can be a poor estimate of the true intensity and can lead to poor estimates of the inhomogeneous K function. To check if this may be the problem, try using the argument sigma to control the smoothing bandwidth.

Simulation envelopes of inhomogeneous K functions need careful attention to ensure that the envelopes are valid. Users often get this wrong. See pages 400-401 of the spatstat book. (Incidentally these are significance envelopes, not confidence envelopes.)

The inhomogeneous K function is not defined for all inhomogeneous point processes, but only for those which are "correlation-stationary" (page 243 of the spatstat book). If the true point process is not correlation-stationary then contradictory results can be obtained from using the software.


